# Can the same SQL query be run against a SQL Server 2012 column-based table and an earlier row-based table on an earlier version of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a problem where using the column-based storage feature in SQL Server 2012 would help out a lot.  There are already a bunch of people using earlier versions of SQL Server that won't be able to upgrade.

In theory, is it possible to create a table that works optimally on both?

I'm hoping that a client running any SQL Server reports could work both against a 2012 columnar instance and a non-columnar standard instance table where the only difference is the 2012 one is faster.

Is this doable?

What would I need to watch out for when reading/writing massive amounts of data in a storage-type agnostic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible to have SQL queries that are compatible both with earlier version of SQL and with 2012. Most things should be fine unless you were using deprecated functionality in the earlier versions or the new features from 2012 (you'd probably know if you were).

Here's a link to Microsoft's summary of changes in SQL 2012 that you might need to watch out for http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707787.aspx.

Comment: thanks for the response.  i'm specifically hoping to use the columnar features which first appeared in 2012 for read/write with as little of checking if (@@version is 2012) as possible when talking to an older version of SQL...